# How to extract one value at a time?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to add a '/fact' command with Telebot module which returns a fact about dogs from API. However, I want it to return only one fact at a time, and a new one each time. I just don't know how to approach the issue. Here's my code:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['fact'])
def get_fact(message):
    index = 0
    while True:
        facts = requests.get('https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs?index=' + str(index)).json()
        f = facts[0]['fact']
        index += 1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f)
```

OR:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['fact'])
def get_fact(message):
        facts = requests.get('https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs/all').json()
        f = list(facts)
        iterator = iter(f)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, iterator.__next__()['fact'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the index outside of the command function definition so that it is not reset every time, with that you can then fetch a fact from the dog facts API and confirm that a fact was received from the JSON payload. If it is empty then reset the factIndex back to 1 and start again, this way you display a new fact every time until you reach the end of the fact list.

```py
factIndex = 1 # Start the index

@bot.message_handler(commands=['fact'])
def get_fact(message):
    facts = json.loads(requests.get("https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs?index=" + str(factIndex)).content)
    
    # Check to see if we obtained a fact
    if (not facts): # If we got not fact
        factIndex = 1 # Reset the index
        facts = json.loads(requests.get("https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs?index=" + str(factIndex)).content)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, facts[0]["fact"])
```

Comment: As far as I understand, I need to globalize factIndex to use it, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - if you place it within the function then it is reset every time.